Usage of もらえる in this sentence

Context: The character is inviting a friend/classmate to a party of the rakugo club. So he tells him "You come to, people who don't do rakugo also come". It's not clear if the character speaking is a first year, but given they are in the same lecture, it seems the case.
However, I'm struggling with this usage of もらえる. My reading would be (from the vague context) that the  first year can get a discount? why is もらえる used over もらう?

As you understand, using the potential form adds ... can get ... Related: Nuance of もらう in 毎日使ってもらえるものがいい

Related for reference What is the difference between もらう and もらえる in this sentence?

There seems to be nothing tricky about the usage of this もらう. This is the most basic example sentence using もらう as a donatory verb.

安い: "inexpensive"
安くする: "to make it inexpensive" → "to discount"
安くしてもらう: "to receive the favor of discounting" → "to have it discounted"
安くしてもらえる: "can have it discounted"

Note that this 1年 is short for 1年生 ("first-grade students"), not 1年間 ("for one year"). Maybe this is what threw you off?

1年はちょっと安くしてもらえる。
First-grade students can get a small discount.

